# Container view constraints just refuse to work

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have spent 6 hours on this container view, and I just can't understand what I am doing wrong.

I have a `container view` inside a view controller created in `storyboard`,in screen size.

I have set its background(container) to be green, so I can see it .

I don't load anything to it. just want to see it on the screen.

I set its constraints to be pinned from all 4 sides.

```
leading space to superview
trailing space to superview
bottom space to superview
top space to superview .
```

I did NOT set its width and height, because as I see it - I don't have to .

I am expecting to see a green square filling the screen.

**On simulator on all iPhones, I see a white screen- the container disappeared .
If I load a controller to the container - I than see half screen green, half screen the view controller.**

I just can't seem to understand why such a simple thing will not work.
Doing the same with `UIView`, will work as expected; the view will be covering the screen.

**EDIT:**

Removing constrains from the container- just solve all the problem, it than works as expected on every device . I JUST DONT GET THE CONSTRAINS !!!

Comment: Please add screenshot of view and its constraints

Comment: What do you mean when you say half screen. Also, if the view controller appearing on "half the screen" the embedded one in the container, or the view controller of the superview? Need more information, pics would be nice.

Comment: Thanks both, he doesn't let me upload images :( what happens is that if you imagine the screen, than vertically dividing it , so on the left part i see the view controller(squeezed to this width) ,and on the right side i see green background.  But leave that for a second. why i dont see the container on screen when i dont load anything to it ? just see it on screen with the green background ?

Comment: Try to take a container,set its background, set its constrains, and see if you can see it covering the screen.